# Cloud Dataflow: Step to read csv file on AWS S3 (TextIO.read) sometimes get stuck

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

example code is below.

```java
// Java
// Apache Beam SDK verison: 2.16.0

final TupleTag<TableRow> successTag = new TupleTag<TableRow>() {};
final TupleTag<TableRow> deadLetterTag = new TupleTag<TableRow>() {};
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(dataflowOptions)

PCollection<String> input = p.apply("ReadS3File", TextIO.read().from("s3://sourceBucket/sourceFilename.csv"));
PCollectionTuple outputTuple = input.apply("StringToBigQueryTableRow", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, TableRow>() { /**/ }))).withOutputTags(successTag, TupleTagList.of(deadLetterTag)))
```

ReadS3File step gets stuck.

I'm reading the Dataflow documentation and examining the thread dump, it appears to be stuck at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read

[Common error guidance](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#processing-stuck)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to determine the root cause of the issue by analysing the thread dump, but I'm afraid it's not enough. I would recommend you to open a case on Google Cloud Platform, because this requires more information on your part which shouldn't be publicly shared in here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I will try to contact support.